# Creating A Grid Layout For IPhone App

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa, ios5

I am in the middle of developing an IPhone app, the app currently takes a photo and stores the  image.

I then have a set of filters that will edit the image. My goal is to have a preview of the image in a grid layout, say 3 x 4 but I am not sure how to go about it. Do I use a uitable for example?

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [DTGridView](https://github.com/danielctull/DTGridView)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIImageView to show your image.